# Loading a tensorflow saved model as a keras model

Tags: python-3.x, keras, tensorflow2.0

I have this MoViNet a0 model for action recognition. I want to load the model (.pb) as a Keras model. My objective is to :modify the model, adjust layers etc ..., using Keras high level API.

The model files are as follows :

- variables directory
- keras_metadata.pb
- saved_model.pb

I tried loading the model with this :

```
loaded_model = tf.saved_model.load(saved_model_path)
```

With **saved_model_path** containing the path to the model directory.

But the resulting object of type **'_UserObject'** does not offer the same flexibilty as a Keras model.

I tried to get the signatures using this :

```
print(loaded_model.signatures)
```

Got the following signatures keys : **'call'** & **'init_states'**

I tried this :

```
cloned_model = tf.keras.models.clone_model(loaded_model)
```

got the following error : **type object '_UserObject' has no attribute 'from_config'**

Is it possible to load the model as a keras model ?